# Running Java/Selenium/Cucumber tests via command line

Tags: java, selenium, maven, automated-tests, cucumber

I have a test project built in Intellij IDEA 2021.1 using Selenium, Cucumber and Maven
The project runs fine from within Intellij but now I want to call the tests from the command line and only those with a specific tag. Below is the project layout

[image]

There is only 1 feature file at present and I only want to call the scenarios with the "regression" tag from the command line.

I have run command line with Visual Studio/Selenium in the past but this is my first go with Java so any advice on how to get this started would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to execute following

```
mvn verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags not @ignore"
```

Or

```
mvn verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @runme"
```

where @runme is a tag over Scenario or Feature.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go when I return to work

Answer (score 1):

you can try this command:

```
mvn clean install "-Dcucumber.options=--tags @yourtagName"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go when I return to work